# A "generalized" exponential power series

Tags: summation, power-series, exponential-sum

I'm wondering if

$$ e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} $$

what would this be

$$  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k+\alpha}}{\Gamma(k+\alpha)} = \large{?}_{\alpha}(x) $$

for $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

What is the the name of this series? Is it known for particular values of $\alpha$, for example $\alpha=1/2$?

Comment: hypergeometric maybe?

Comment: Can be expressed with incomplete Gamma functions, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7

Comment: @Alex - "hypergeometric" gives me a direction - it would then be something like $_{1}F_{1}(1;\alpha;x)$, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not a big expert in these problems, hope others help you out better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k+a}}{(k+a)!}~=~e^x~\bigg[1-\dfrac{\Gamma(a,x)}{\Gamma(a)}\bigg].$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you point. Do you mean that we can generalise the LHS by taking $a \in (0,1)$ in the RHS instead of $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$?

Comment: Also, from the little I know $\Gamma$ is defined for only one argument. What do you mean by $\Gamma(a,x)$?

Comment: $\Gamma(a,x)$ is the incomplete gamma

Comment: @A.P.: See [Incomplete $\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Lucian and Alex, such a function can be expressed in terms of an incomplete Gamma function or a hypergeometric function $\phantom{}_{1} F_1$. I just wanted to add that for $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ we have something that depends on the error function:

> $$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^{k+1/2}}{(k+1/2)!} = e^x\operatorname{Erf}(\sqrt{x})=\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}e^{-y^2}\,dy.$$